# How to create custom metrics for use in Tensorflow's Estimator class?

Tags: tensorflow

In Tensorflow's [Creating Estimators in tf.estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/extend/estimators) guide, the example used a metric that is already predefined in the `tf.metrics` module.

Are there any resources that describe how to define a custom metric that can be used to evaluate an Estimator? I'd like to implement the F1 metric.